# union in powershell regular expressions

Tags: regex, powershell

Does powershell's implementation of regexes have a union ("or") function, or will I have to match against multiple regexes separately?

i.e.:

```
PS C:\Users\nacht> ("hello there" -replace "el", "xx") -replace "er", "xx"
hxxlo thxxe
```

i want to be able to do that^ with a single `$re` like so:

```
PS C:\Users\nacht> "hello there" -replace $re, "xx"
hxxlo thxxe
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as I was typing my question, I decided to try a couple things, and it turns out the `|` operator seems to do the trick!

```
PS C:\Users\schwabg> $re = "el|er"
PS C:\Users\schwabg> "hello there" -replace $re, "xx"
hxxlo thxxe
```

Not documented in the top google pages...

Comment: The pipe `|` char is a basic regex alteration and means `or`. Yuour expression will match sequence `e, l or e, r`. [Read more](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) [about regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/).

Comment: yes i know, but it wasnt in any documentation i had found so for some reason i assumed it didnt work. Just figured I would save someone some googling time. Why document the kleene star and character classes but not union?

Comment: I just fed `regex or` into Google, and each of the top 5 results does document this.